# nodejs and babel: import from results in not defined

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Model/Company/index.js:

```
import {Schema} from 'mongoose';
import CompanyAddressSchema from '../CompanyAddress';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const companySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 80, required: true},
    type: {type: Schema.Types.String, minlength: 1, maxlength: 80, required: true},
    companyAddress: [CompanyAddressSchema]
    }, { timestamps: true });

const Company = mongoose.model(‘Company’, companySchema);

export default Company;
```

CompanyService(call at top of file):

```
import Company from '../models/Company';
```

Company Service(the query to get the data:

```
let company = await Company.findOne({_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId(id)});
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"],
   "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread",
     "transform-async-to-generator",
     "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
     "transform-builtin-extend",
     "add-module-exports",
     ["transform-runtime", {
     "polyfill": false,
     "regenerator": true
   }]]
}
```

The issue here is that Company ends up being undefined.  I am not sure how this could be undefined if I declared it at the top of the file.  What could be causing this and what is a way to fix it?

**Update**: I noticed that if I replace the import statement with

"let Company = require(../models/Company).default"

I get the correct object.  How can I achieve this using the import statement?

Comment: `import Company.findOne ...` is not valid syntax. I'm surprised Babel doesn't error for you.

Comment: Sorry.  That was a cut and paste mistake.  The modified code above is the actual example.